# Get a SelectAll from Union in Shapeless / scala

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have a `Union` created from two `HList`, let say `E` and `F`. From this `Union`, I would like to get back a new `HList` with type `E`. It will  not necessarily have the same value than the original list, but I don't care, I only want a `HList` with the correct type

in practice, what I want could be summarized in one function :

 `def selectFromUnion[E <: HList, F <: HList](u: Union[E, F]): SelectAll[u.Out, E] = ???`

Does someone know how I can implement that? Or if shapeless has already something to do that?

EDIT : if I can be more precise, I want a proof that a Union of 2 `HList` contains the type of the original `HList`s. We can simplify the original problem as searching for :

`implicit def selectFromUnion[E, T <: HList, F <: HList](implicit u: Union[E :: T, F]): Selector[u.Out, E] = ???`

Sadly, I still have no clue as how I can do that.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by `Union` here? What you've written doesn't look like a shapeless labelled coproduct. Do you mean something like `Either` where you just have one of `E` and `F`? Or something like `(,)` where you have both `E` and `F`?

Comment: `Union` is here an instance of the class `shapeless.ops.hlist.Union`.  As I'm new to shapeless, maybe  - probably - I've missed something in the function signature ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution that works for my case, by declaring my own `Union` (copy/pasta for the win) and add an attribute that gives the `SelectAll` instance

```
trait SelectableUnion[L <: HList, M <: HList] extends DepFn2[L, M] with Serializable {
    type Out <: HList

    def selectL: SelectAll[Out, L]

    def selectM: SelectAll[Out, M]
  }

  trait LowPriorityUnion {
    type Aux[L <: HList, M <: HList, Out0 <: HList] = SelectableUnion[L, M] {type Out = Out0}
  }

  object SelectableUnion extends LowPriorityUnion {
    def apply[L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit union: SelectableUnion[L, M]): Aux[L, M, union.Out] = union

    // let ∅ ∪ M = M
    implicit def hlistUnion[M <: HList]: Aux[HNil, M, M] =
      new SelectableUnion[HNil, M] {
        type Out = M

        def apply(l: HNil, m: M): Out = m

        override def selectL: SelectAll[M, HNil] = SelectAll.hnilSelectAll

        override def selectM: SelectAll[M, M] = new SelectAll[M, M] {
          override def apply(t: M): M = t
        }
      }

    // let (H :: T) ∪ M  =  H :: (T ∪ M) when H ∉ M
    implicit def hlistUnion1[H, T <: HList, M <: HList]
    (implicit
      u: SelectableUnion[T, M],
      f: FilterNot.Aux[M, H, M]
    ): Aux[H :: T, M, H :: u.Out] =
      new SelectableUnion[H :: T, M] {
        type Out = H :: u.Out

        def apply(l: H :: T, m: M): Out = l.head :: u(l.tail, m)

        override def selectL: SelectAll[::[H, u.Out], ::[H, T]] = new SelectAll[H :: u.Out, H :: T] {
          override def apply(t: H :: u.Out): H :: T = (t.head) :: u.selectL(t.tail)
        }

        override def selectM: SelectAll[::[H, u.Out], M] = new SelectAll[H :: u.Out, M] {
          override def apply(t: ::[H, u.Out]): M = u.selectM.apply(t.tail)
        }
      }

    // let (H :: T) ∪ M  =  H :: (T ∪ (M - H)) when H ∈ M
    implicit def hlistUnion2[H, T <: HList, M <: HList, MR <: HList]
    (implicit
      r: Remove.Aux[M, H, (H, MR)],
      u: SelectableUnion[T, MR]
    ): Aux[H :: T, M, H :: u.Out] =
      new SelectableUnion[H :: T, M] {
        type Out = H :: u.Out

        def apply(l: H :: T, m: M): Out = l.head :: u(l.tail, r(m)._2)

        override def selectL: SelectAll[::[H, u.Out], ::[H, T]] = new SelectAll[H :: u.Out, H :: T] {
          override def apply(t: H :: u.Out): H :: T = (t.head) :: u.selectL(t.tail)
        }

        override def selectM: SelectAll[::[H, u.Out], M] = new SelectAll[H :: u.Out, M] {
          override def apply(t: ::[H, u.Out]): M = r.reinsert(t.head, u.selectM(t.tail))
        }
      }
  }
```

and then you can write

```
def selectFromUnion[E <: HList, F <: HList](u: SelectableUnion[E, F]): SelectAll[u.Out, E] = u.selectL
```